# What does this Regex pattern mean: '/&\w;/'

Tags: php, regex

Can someone explain what this function

```
preg_replace('/&\w;/', '', $buf)
```

does? I have looked at various tutorials and found that it replaces the pattern `/&\w;/` with string `''`. But I can't understand the pattern `/&\w;/`. What does it represent?

Similarly in

```
preg_match_all("/(\b[\w+]+\b)/", $buf, $words)
```

I can't understand what does the string `"/(\b[\w+]+\b)/"` represents.

Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sorry @Codeur, @Gordon you are correct. I would join the recommendation below of http://www.regular-expressions.info/ as a good place to start.

Answer (score 11):

The explanation of your first expression is simple, it is:

```
&     # Match the character “&” literally
\w    # Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores)
;     # Match the character “;” literally
```

The second one is:

```
(           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \b          # Assert position at a word boundary
   [\w+]       # Match a single character present in the list below
                  # A word character (letters, digits, and underscores)
                  # The character “+”
      +           # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \b          # Assert position at a word boundary
)
```

The `preg_replace` function makes use of regular expressions. Regular expressions allow you to find patterns in text in a really powerful way.

To be able to use functions like `preg_replace` or `preg_match` I recommend you to take a look first at how regular expressions work.

You can gather a lot of info on this site http://www.regular-expressions.info/

And you can use software tools to help you understand the regex (like [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/))

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions, \w stands for any "word" character. That is: a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore. \b stands for "word boundary", that is the beginning and end of a word (a series of word characters).

So, `/&\w;/` is a regular expression to match the & sign, followed by a series of word characters, followed by a ;. For example, `&foobar;` would match, and preg_replace will replace it with an empty string.

In that same manner, `/(\b[\w+]+\b)/` matches a word boundary, followed by multiple word characters, followed by another word boundary. The words are captured separately using the parenthesis. So, this regular expression will simply return the words in a string as an array.

Comment: `s/a series/a single/` in the second paragraph.